# Better quality texture when zooming

Tags: xna, c#, textures

Is there any way to have better quality textures ?

I thought that creating huge textures will improve their quality in game, that's why I draw textures with 0.25f or 0.5f scale.

I understand that computer can't display 4 pixels in 1 screen pixel, but how people do to have beautiful sprites while zooming ? even on smartphones...

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [Mipmapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap).

Comment: Perfect ;)
ths a lot

Answer (score 2):

equally they could be using vector art work that scales infinitly without pixelating

another method that high end game engines use is detail maps - its an extra texture that is overlaid onto the asset/wall/model when the player is very close to said asset

see a better explanation here - http://wiki.polycount.net/DetailMap

Comment: +1 Vector art is great for zooming. (Though it takes a special rendering steps)